# Django, CreateView - How can I create child objects after saving the form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to allow user to create a post with multiple images attached to it. I have 2 models, Post, and Image attached to it with foreign key.

When the user submits the form, the Post object doesn't exist yet, so I don't yet have anything to attach images to.

The way I understand it, in my CreateView, after user submits a form, I am supposed to:

- Create the post out of the form data, save it.
- Get image files from the form data.
- Create images and attach them to the post.

Can you help me to figure out what is the right way to do this?
(or suggest a different implementation)

Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Well, you gave the answer already.

Comment: I'm just having trouble figuring out how to properly implement it with CBVs.

Comment: Add your recent code to the post and describe the actual problem you have with it. Then we can help.